# Selenium (with EC and WebDriverWait) not detecting element even though it is present

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

So, I am using selenium and chromedriver in python to automate some tasks. I need to wait for an iframe that gets created upon clicking a button. The issue is that when I use WebDriverWait and EC to wait until the iframe becomes present, it times out.

```
...code...

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='x'|@id='y'|@id='z']")))
except:
    print ("iframe not loaded")
```

But when I test using just....

`EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='x'|@id='y'|@id='z']"))`

...the element gets found.

Even using..

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='x'|@id='y'|@id='z']")`

..works!

What am I doing wrong in the `try-except` block to prevent the element from being found?

Comment: Can you share your full code and the website that we can have a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I cant share the site unfortunately; its an internal uni page. I'll think of adding more info..Thanks

Comment: Please post the HTML of all  `iframe` element?

Comment: The error is most likely due to the `OR` operator `|`. Is my usage correct?